# Bounds for MLP hyperparameter search

Tags: neural-network, hyperparameter

I'm trying to optimize a neural network architecture for a particular problem, but there just seems to be so many hyperparameters that I'm concerned that there are much better options that I'm not exploring (e.g. I might be getting trapped in a local minima for hyperparams).

Essentially, I'd like some standard bounds for hyperparameter search. Ideally, if a person were to see the breadth of explored parameters, they might be reasonably certain to try another class of machine learning models. In particular, I am looking for concrete advice on at least

What size neurons to include in the search

- The number of hidden layers, and the width of the layers
- The
  optimizer and learning rates
- Activation functions and loss functions

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

In designing an MLP architecture, we can restrict ourselves to 4-8 layers with 8-128 (power of 2) neurons per layer. In addition, we can assume [recommended](http://cs231n.github.io/) ReLU activations with He normal weight initialization and Adam or SGD with Nesterov momentum optimizers (see [ipython notebook](https://github.com/vsmolyakov/experiments_with_python/blob/master/chp03/tensorflow_optimizers.ipynb) for comparison). Your loss function will depend on the problem: cross-entropy for classification and MSE for regression.

In order to avoid local optima in parameter search, it's better to use [random search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) or [bayesian optimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization). For additional answers, see this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22199/what-are-the-default-values-of-nodes-and-internal-layers-in-neural-network-model/22289).