# What are the default values of nodes and internal layers in Neural Network models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

What is the default number of internal layers and internal nodes in training a neural network?

My data has 62 observations with roughly 200 predictors. I have a target variable with two classes and implemented a neural network with one internal layer and one internal node without repeats. Also, I tried with two internal layers, with 5 internal nodes in one, and 2 internal nodes in second layer. I want to find the accuracy, first, on default values and then I will try to optimize the model performance.

What is the criterion to choose the number of layers and internal nodes in a neural network training model? In the case of Random Forest, we can choose to try to be roughly equal to the square root of the number of predictors.

Comment: i would worry about over-fitting (given there are only 62 observations and 200 predictors). i suggest regularizing the network using l1 or l2 penalty on weights and dropout with keep probability of 0.5

Comment: You are in the right direction. Please read this[paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01578) that tried to answer your question. Welcome the world of Neural Architecture Search (NAS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential approach can be iterative design of a neural network architecture such as Multi-Layer Perceptron (MLP) as described in the following post:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238637/deep-neural-network-tuning-hyperparameters

We can restrict ourselves to 4-8 layers with 8-128 (power of 2) neurons per layer. In addition, we can assume [recommended](http://cs231n.github.io/) ReLU activations with He normal weight initialization and Adam or SGD with Nesterov momentum optimizers.

In order to avoid overfitting on a small dataset, it is important to add l1 or l2 regularization (weight decay) and a dropout layer (e.g. with keep probability of 0.5).

We can then use cross validation with [random search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) or [bayesian optimization](https://github.com/fmfn/BayesianOptimization) to choose the best architecture as described in the cross validated article above.

Answer (score 3):

There are websites that explain these pretty well.

**Deciding on the number of neurons in the hidden layer(s)**

From https://www.r-bloggers.com/selecting-the-number-of-neurons-in-the-hidden-layer-of-a-neural-network/:

> The most common rule of thumb is to choose a number of hidden neurons between 1 and the number of input variables.

**Deciding on the number of layers of hidden layers**

From https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw:

> For most problems, one could probably get decent performance (even without a second optimization step) by setting the hidden layer configuration using just two rules: (i) number of hidden layers equals one; and (ii) the number of neurons in that layer is the mean of the neurons in the input and output layers.

Hope that answers your question!